# Simplify to vectors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic

How do you simplify an expression:
$[r_1, r_2, r_3]^T [t_1, t_2, t_3] = r_1 t_1 + r_2 t_2 + r_3 t_3 = \vec{r}^T \vec{t}$

In other words, I want to group and simplify scalar expressions over vectors / matrices (which mathematica outputs by default) into vector and matrix notation

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Can you please give us a concrete example by choosing scalar values perhaps? Also evaluate: `{a, b, c}\[Transpose] . {g, h, i}`. Mathematica doesn't differentiate between row and column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

One has to proceed cautiously because Mathematica accepts non-standard algebraic input with vectors and matrices, e.g a.b instead of  a.Transpose[{b]]  such that dimensions fit for the  contraction process row * column:  {a_i} . {{b_1},..}

In the  simplified form

```
J = Range[3];
R = Subscript[r, #] & /@ J
T = Subscript[t, #] & /@ J
R . T
```

$$\left\{r_1,r_2,r_3\right\}$$
$$\left\{t_1,t_2,t_3\right\}$$
$$r_1 t_1+r_2 t_2+r_3 t_3$$

```
R . T /. {((Subscript[a_, #] &) /@ J) . ((Subscript[b_, #] &) /@ 
   J) :> 
     \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)\[Transpose] . 
       \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(b\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)} // TraditionalForm
```

$$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{r}^T.\overset{\rightharpoonup }{t}$$

Much code about nearly nothing and mathematically undefined if vectors are not defined as one column arrays.